# how to increase all product prices in adonis migration file

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, adonis.js

I have a Prdoucts table and what I need to do is increase the value of this table's price column by 20% how can I accomplish this using adonis version 5 migrations.

this is what I have tried:

```
import BaseSchema from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Schema'

export default class extends BaseSchema {
  protected tableName = 'products'

  public async up() {
    this.defer(async (db) => {
      const products = await db.from('products').select('*').increment('price','products_price'*20/100)
    })
  }

  public async down() {
    this.schema.dropTable(this.tableName)
  }
}
```

Comment: please add more code and what you have tried and where you stuck in code.

Answer (score 2):

From a SQL point of view you just need to run a statement like the following:

```sql
update Prdoucts set price = price * 1.2;
```

In order to run this as part of a adonis migration [the documentation says](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/migrations#performing-other-database-operations):

> Quite often, you will have requirements to run SQL queries other than just creating/altering tables. For example: Migrating data to a newly created table before deleting the old table.
>
> You should define these operations using the this.defer method

As to how to execute the operation there might be a way doing this using [the Adonis Query Builder](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/orm/query-builder), but probably the easiest is to just [run a raw update](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/query-builder#using-raw-queries-1):

```js
Database
      .raw(`update Prdoucts set price = price * 1.2`, [])
```

Comment: I used your query directly on my database (outside migration files) there must be a way to do it in query builder but Im not fammiliar enough,but you solved my issue and thank you for that